# How to show data from table row according to the table ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text box and a submit button, I'm wanting whatever number(ID) thats inside the text box to show the information from that row. via the method `<%=ev.id%>`

Heres my controller (this is all i have rails at the moment)

`@events = Event.where(id: params[:id])`

And this is my html

```
      <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Event ID Here"/>
        <button type="btn btn-block btn-info" class="btn2" value="Submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
  <% @event.each do |ev| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form should be like this:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "controller_name", action: "action_name"}, method: "method_type") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:id, "Input the ID to display:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:id) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit ID") %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
@id = params[:id]
```

And in your view, just:

```
<%= @id %>
```

Comment: Sorry , i only want the id thats entered in the search box to display, so if id 19 is put in the search box then the details for that would only show

Comment: ok, then have a instance variable: `@id = params[:id]` in your controller and display that in view.

Comment: How would i be able to input the id i want the detials for? e.g. if i want id 19's details

Comment: You can put it in a text field and grab it from the `params` hash in your controller.

Comment: I see you already have a text field for that. In your controller action: `puts params.inspect` Then, you can see how the `id` is coming inside the `params` hash. Then, you will just grab it from there and assign to `@id`.

Comment: So i did what you said to do, And typed in id 96, Nothing came up because i dont have anything for the input button?

Comment: See this: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/how-to-specify-controller-and-action-in-rails-form/
Submit the `id` in similar fashion from the view. Then grab it in the controller and assign to `@id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88602/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-ddsbro).

Answer (score 0):

You have variable `@events` in your controller but in `view` you have `@event` and also you need to print the array information. You need to use `<%= %>`

```
<% @events.each do |ev| %>
 <%= puts ev %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry , i only want the id thats entered in the search box to display, so if id 19 is put in the search box then the details for that would only show

Comment: what are the details?

Comment: details? as in what columns exist in the db? I details in my db at the moment, I need it to show the details for the specific id :)